MudBlazor ChildContent property error on a MudButton inside à MudExpansionPanel
Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to set property 'ChildContent' on object of type 'MudBlazor.MudButton'. The error was: Specified cast is not valid.

I have this error while working on a project and didn't find anything online to solve it.
It seems like the MudExpansionPanel is doing something that bug the MudButton.
It happens at (seemingly) random times while I test my app so I don't really know what caused it.
EDIT: It happens after exactly 8 interactions with a MudExpansionPanel. Doesn't matter which one, in which order, if it's the same or different ones, or if it's opening or closing a panel.
I'm using the latest version of both Blazor and MudBlazor.
Here is the relevant code :
<MudExpansionPanels MultiExpansion="true">
@foreach (var equip in equipement.ListEquipements)
{
    <MudExpansionPanel Text="@equip.Nom">
        <MudGrid>
            <MudItem xs="4">
                <MudText>Id : @equip.EquipementId</MudText>
                @if (equip.TypeCapteurId != null)
                {
                    <MudText>Type Capteur : @equip.TypeCapteurId</MudText>
                }
            </MudItem>
            <MudItem xs="4">
                <MudText>Px : @equip.PositionX</MudText>
                <MudText>Py : @equip.PositionY</MudText>
                <MudText>Pz : @equip.PositionZ</MudText>
            </MudItem>
            <MudItem xs="4">
                <MudText>Dx : @equip.DimensionX</MudText>
                <MudText>Dy : @equip.DimensionY</MudText>
                <MudText>Dz : @equip.DimensionZ</MudText>
            </MudItem>
        </MudGrid>
        <div class="d-flex justify-end gap-2">
            <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" DropShadow="false" Color="Color.Default">Supprimer</MudButton>
            <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" DropShadow="false" Color="Color.Primary">Modifier</MudButton>
        </div>
    </MudExpansionPanel>
}


Can you create a reproducible example here https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ and add that to your question
